# Has anyone created custom StyleCop and FxCop rules for the Lance Hunt C# coding standards?

Tags: c#, coding-style, fxcop, stylecop

I've just started work at a shop that uses Lance Hunt's coding standards for C# development (see [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/lhunt/pages/CSharp-Coding-Standards-document.aspx)) -- has anyone customised StyleCop and FxCop to work with these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StyleCop itself already contains a lot from this standard, except some controversial issues like tabs-vs-space indentation or this-vs-prefixed namings.

For this exceptional things StyleCop+ can be used in additional to StyleCop. And it seems that this "pair" could probably implement the standard you mentioned well enough.

*Answering your question more specifically - I've created StyleCop+ which has some rules that might help implementing this standard, like forcing tab indentation or forcing prefixed field names.*

Comment: Ah, nice one - it sounds like this is what I'm after. Tabs-versus-spaces is a particular bugbear -- I don't care myself which are used _so long as people are consistent!_ Do you have a link?

Comment: (indeed, but that comment should increase your page rank!)